# Software for Map Projection?

Tags: image-processing, mapping

I have some planet pics (not from Earth) and I need to create flat images of them in order the combine them in a single planet. The problem is: how I'm going to do this? With some search, I found out that this method is called Map Projection.
http://nationalatlas.gov/articles/mapping/a_projections.html

But I still can't find a software which can convert a planet image to a flat map. If someone is still confuse, I will explain in a different way:

[image: Example]

I want to transform all this little planets in flat pieces and then combine them in Gimp/Photoshop to create a complete flat map of the planet (like the one above them).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found a solution. Geocart:
http://www.mapthematics.com/